# Can the performance of the palindrome detection algorithm in C# be improved with a different approach?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, indexing

I'm trying to implement the most optimized solution (performance wise) for the palyndrome algorithm.
Can we do better than O(n) ? What is the cost of indexing the word here ?

```cs
public bool IsPalindrome(string word)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < word.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] != word[^(1 + i)]) return false;
    }

    return true; //O(n)
}
```

Comment: Create a complete dictionary of all possible palindromes and then do a lookup then you have O(1). Practical? Presumably not.

Comment: How would you calc hash of string in sub O(n)?

Comment: Your algorithm looks pretty much optimal to me. Note that very clever algorithms like QuickSort (unrelated to your problem) tend to be outperformed by stupid simple algorithms like Straight Insertion for a small number of elements. And words usually have a small number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to benchmark the time this method takes to check if a sample string is a palindrome but I have minimized it as much as possible

```
   public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
    {
        int left = 0;
        int right = word.Length - 1;

        while (left < right)
        {
            if (word[left] != word[right])
                return false;

            left++;
            right--;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, yes it still works without the `ToArray` call. Thank You for pointing that out

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used the BenchmarkDotNet to see the difference between your method and mine and It was super interesting. The result were 130.6614ns for your suggested method and 0.5244ns for the one I posted. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yours is already as optimal

Comment: @Rayane, I have updated my answer, the new one should beat O(n). Try it out and let me know.